# Difference Between DataReader and Dataset?

Tags: c#

I want convert this code into using a `DataSet`.

I don't have any idea how to retrieve data from a `DataSet`.

```
 conn.Open();

 string strquery = "select * from tblclientinfo where clientId=" +
 txtid.Text; SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, conn);

 SqlDataReader sqldreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

 if (sqldreader.HasRows)
 {
    while (sqldreader.Read())
    {
       txtid.Text = sqldreader["clientId"].ToString();
       txtname.Text = sqldreader["name"].ToString();
       txtmobile.Text = sqldreader["mobile"].ToString();
       txtcnic.Text = sqldreader["cnic"].ToString();
    }
 }
 else
 {
    MessageBox.Show("Record for ID" + " " + txtid.Text + " " + "Not Found !");
 }

 sqldreader.Close();
 conn.close();
```

Comment: ***Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.***

Comment: +1 for mentioned injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this ?

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from tblclientinfo where clientId = @id";
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtid);
da.SelectCommand.Connection = conn;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   txtid.Text = row["clientId"].ToString();
   txtname.Text = row["name"].ToString();
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks 
now can you please explain 
how to read ds and get desire value

Comment: @user3257950 I have added a sample foreach loop.

Comment: Exactly this is what a Want 
Thanks Alot

Answer (score 0):

The `DataReader` is the active part reading in the data from the database connection.
The `DataSet` is a container defined in a generic way so that it may contain any structure of data that tis read in by a `DataReader`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
// Assumes that conn is a valid SqlConnection object.
string strquery = "select * from tblclientinfo where clientId=" + txtid.Text;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strquery , conn);

DataSet resultSet = new DataSet();
resultSet.Fill(resultSet, "resultSet");

//now you can read data from DataTables contained in your dataset and do whatever with it
DataTable FirstTableOfDataSet = resultSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Thanks 
now my data is in table[0];

Comment: You're welcome, if that solved your situation you can mark answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As your question asks about the difference, so here it goes:

1. DataReader is used in connected architecture. That means a connection remains open till you iterate through and fetch all records one by one. Only after fetching records when you write con.Close() it gets closed.
2. DataSet and DataAdapter are used in disconnected Architecture. That means they bring data and do not have a open connection for a long time. So in case if the database get changed after bringing data you won't have the updates, because it is cached.

Take an example: 
An oil company is located at say Dubai(DataSource - Database), it needs to send oil to say USA(Application UI). What are the two ways?

1. A jet plane carries the oil to USA.- Disconnected. The jet plane is the DataAdapter and the container in which the oil is brought is dataset/datatable.
2. A pipeline runs through Dubai to USA. - Connected. The pipeline is the reader.

Awkward example. ;) Hope this make the difference little clear.